# Round to Integer in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am currently building my first stuff on Smalltalk and I have hit an issue. I have to deal with a user-entered number, and I need to div it by 2 and still be an integer. If an user inputs 10, I will work with 5, if they input 11, I have to work with 6, but I will obviously get 5.5.

If I could get the mod of a number I could simply make sure mod = 0 else add 0.5 and it would do just as good, but I just can't find how to make a mod operation in SmallTalk, all my searches end up in unrelated stuff about actual social smalltalk, which is extremely frustrating.

So if you could tell me how to get the mod of a number it would be great, if you could tell me how to round up with a separate function, even better. Thanks for your help and time beforehand.

**UPDATE: After some research, I tried to do it this way:**

```
mod := par rem: 2.
mod = 0 ifFalse: [ par := par + 0.5 ].
```

where as "mod" is mod of the variable "par", and if it isn't 0, it should add up 0.5 to par.

My issue now is that trying to use par in a timesRepeat brings up a "BoxedFloat64 did not understand #timesRepeat" error. So I am still in the same issue, or just need a way to make a float into an integer.

Comment: Could you please specify what dialect are you using? e.g. pharo, squeak, vw, ...?

Comment: Pharo, altough my issue has already been fixed, thank you. However, if you know how to convert a float (that doesn't has a decimal part) to integer it would be really helpful for future reference.

Comment: You can always browse the methods of BoxedFloat64 and its superclasses (Squeak has a "browse protocol" feature that lets you browse all of them at the same time, but I do not know whether it is still available in Pharo and how it is called there). Number has an `asInteger` method that truncates the float (which is not exactly what you want, but it could guide you to further methods). There is also `roundUpTo:`, `roundTo:` and `rounded`. The binary message for integer division is `//` and its modulo companion is double-backslash.

Comment: How exactly would you repeat a loop 2.5 times? You can't. Hence it does not make sense to send that message to a Float (Boxed or nor Boxed), be it a Float with no decimal part...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of ways. For example

Add 1 to entered number before div by 2 if entered number is odd

```
temp := enteredNumber.
temp odd ifTrue: [temp := temp + 1 ].
^temp / 2
```

Using ceiling method

```
^(enteredNumber / 2) ceiling
```

Answer (score 5):

In Smalltalk, we have an operator for integer division (and even two operators):

```
11 / 2
```

would answer a `Fraction`, not a whole `Integer`
But:

```
11 // 2
```

would answer the quotient of division, rounded toward negative infinity
And the corresponding remainder will be:

```
11 \\ 2
```

The second operator `quo:` for quotient and `rem:` for remainder
The difference is only with negative receiver/operand: the later ones are truncating the quotient toward zero.

```
-11 // 4 = -3. "floored toward negative infinity"
-11 \\ 4 = 1.
(-11 quo: 4) = -2. "truncated toward zero"
(-11 rem: 4) = -3.
```

If you want to round the quotient upper (toward positive infinity), then you can write:

```
(anInteger + 1) // 2.
```

Or same without parenthesis if you are confident enough in binary operator precedence:

```
anInteger + 1 // 2.
```